# Need help changing menu from hover to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

--- Original Hover code ---

```
function bind_dropdown() {
    $('div#quick_nav div.search_dropdown').on('hover', function() {
        var thisid = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var this_action = thisid[1];
        var this_width = 950;
        var add_class = 'dropdown_full';

        if(this_action == 4) {
            this_width = 200;
            add_class = 'dropdown_small';
        }

        if($('div#quick_nav div#dropdown_'+escape(this_action)).is(':visible')) {
            $('div#quick_nav div#dropdown_'+escape(this_action)).addClass(add_class).slideUp(100);
        }
        else{
            $('div#quick_nav div.dropdown').hide();
            $('div#quick_nav div#dropdown_'+escape(this_action)).addClass(add_class).slideDown(100).width(this_width);
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

--- End Original Code ---

I did try and change hover to click.  It works however to close the menu you now have to click on the menu icon again.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I would like to be able to click to show menu and when the mouse moves off the menu it would close automatically.

Thank you in advance

J

Comment: Use onClick event to show menu and onMouseLeave to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
function bind_dropdown() {
    $('div#quick_nav div.search_dropdown').on('click', function() {
        var thisid = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var this_action = thisid[1];
        var this_width = 950;
        var add_class = 'dropdown_full';

        if(this_action == 4) {
            this_width = 200;
            add_class = 'dropdown_small';
        }

        if($('div#quick_nav div#dropdown_'+escape(this_action)).is(':visible')) {
            $('div#quick_nav div#dropdown_'+escape(this_action)).addClass(add_class).slideUp(100);
        }
        return false;
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        var thisid = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var this_action = thisid[1];
        var this_width = 950;
        var add_class = 'dropdown_full';

        if(this_action == 4) {
            this_width = 200;
            add_class = 'dropdown_small';
        }
        $('div#quick_nav div.dropdown').hide();
        $('div#quick_nav div#dropdown_'+escape(this_action)).addClass(add_class).slideDown(100).width(this_width);
    });
}
```